# using vectors that hold unknown object types

Tags: c++, object, vector, stl, void-pointers

I'm trying to use an std::vector where I don't know the type.  I've been able to convert the vector and pass it to and from functions.  But I can't figure out if it is possible to access the objects within the vector without knowing the object type.  I do know that the objects will always be pointers.  Is it possible to access the size of the vector and the objects it holds without knowing the object type?

I have added an example use case below.  The problem I run into is in the PushToLua() function at case MyVariant::VarTypeObjectArray:

The code below allows me to do stuff like this...

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::vector<SomeClass*> vec;
    MyVariant v = &vec; 
    std::vector<SomeClass*>* test = v;
    v.PushToLua();
}
```

---

```
    class SomeClass
    {

    };

    class Wrapper
    {
    };

    template<typename ValueType>
    class ContainerWrapper : public Wrapper
    {
    public:
        ContainerWrapper( ValueType value )
            : m_Container( value )
        {
        }

        ValueType GetValue()
        {
            return m_Container;
        }

        ValueType m_Container;
    };

    class MyVariant
    {
    public:
        enum VarType
        {
            VarTypeVoid,
            VarTypeInt,
            VarTypeUnsignedInt,
            VarTypeFloat,
            VarTypeObjectArray
        };

        union
        {
            int m_Int;
            unsigned int m_UnsignedInt;
            float m_Float;
            Wrapper* m_ObjectArray;
        };

        VarType m_Type;

        template<typename ValueType>
        MyVariant( std::vector<ValueType*>* value )
        {
            //note--not concerned with the "new" and no delete right now. just testing
            ContainerWrapper<std::vector<ValueType*>*>* pTemp = new ContainerWrapper<std::vector<ValueType*>*>( value );
            m_Type = VarTypeObjectArray;
            m_ObjectArray = pTemp;
        }

        template<typename T>
        operator std::vector<T*>*()
        {
            if ( m_Type == VarTypeObjectArray )
            {
                ContainerWrapper<std::vector<T*>*>* pWrapper = static_cast<ContainerWrapper<std::vector<T*>*>*>(m_ObjectArray);
                return pWrapper->GetValue();
            }

            return NULL;
        }

        bool MyVariant::PushToLua( lua_State* L ) const
        {
            switch ( m_Type )
            {
            case MyVariant::VarTypeInt:
            case MyVariant::VarTypeUnsignedInt:
                //lua_pushinteger( L, m_Int );
                return true;
            case MyVariant::VarTypeFloat:
                //lua_pushnumber( L, m_Float );
                return true;
            case MyVariant::VarTypeObjectArray:
                lua_newtable( L );

                //Somehow loop through array and push each address into table
                //I won't know the type here, but i do know its an object
                // ? = cause i can't figure out how
                // I guess the question is, how can i do this?
                ContainerWrapper<std::vector<?*>*>* pWrapper = static_cast<ContainerWrapper<std::vector<?*>*>*>(m_ObjectArray);
                std::vector< ?* >* myArrayOfObjects = pWrapper->GetValue();
                int i = 0;
                for ( auto& object : myArrayOfObjects )
                {
                    //lua_pushlightuserdata( L, object );
                    //lua_rawseti( L, -2, i++ );
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
```

Comment: Use the vector of [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: @Mohit you need to understand what you are trying to achieve when you use `std::any`. 90% requests of "any type" container is from novices who do not understand what they really need

Comment: yeah i thought about using any, or boost::any, or void* depending on the available c++ version.  But then it would not be possible to convert the variant to a typed array via templates.  Am I right?               `template<typename T>
operator std::vector<T*>*()
{
}`